# Find the lowest repeatative element from an unsorted list which contains duplicate elements

Tags: python, time-complexity

Suppose I have an unsorted list which has duplicate elements, but just one element has occurred once. How can I find that unique element in O(n) or better complexity?
My Approach: Using Counter from Collections I got the counts of each element. It gives a sorted dictionary in O(n). But I'm not sure how to get the key with lowest value.

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [1,2,3,2,4,5,1,3,4,9,1,5]
dict1 = Counter(list1)
print (dict1)
```

This gives me an output as Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 9: 1}).
How can I extract the key 9 which has the lowest value 1?
Is there any better approach?

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm not using a set. Rather I looked forward to get the counts and return the element with minimum count value.

Comment: @Prune Oh, if you are only interested in the elements with count === 1, then that’s a really good duplicate – Nice find!

Comment: Why not use a set? When you see a new element, insert it into the set. If the element is already in the set, remove it. Once you've traversed the entire list, the only element in the set will be the unique element.

Comment: @mrshl You would need a second set to make sure that you don’t readd a value that you have removed before.

Comment: @poke there are a lot of duplicates for this in the `algorithms` group.

Comment: @poke That of course depends on the format of the inputs. I took "duplicates" to mean exactly two, maybe a faulty assumption in this case.

Comment: @mrshl For what it’s worth, there are three 1s in OP’s example input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min` with an appropriate `key` argument:

```
>>> min(dict1, key=dict1.get)
9
```

As an iterator, `dict1` yields its keys, but you want `min` to use the associated value to determine the "size" of the key. `dict1.get` is a function that, given a key, returns its value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) to find the smallest count within your dictionary. This is equivalent to what [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) does except that it is using `nlargest` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = [1,2,3,2,4,5,1,3,4,9,1,5]
dict1 = Counter(list1)

smallest = heapq.nsmallest(1, dict1.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
# [(9, 1)]
```

Note that this will not be possible in linear time. You already need linear time to count the elements and you will have to look at your results again to find the smallest result. The heap operations are `O(log n)` though, so `nsmallest` will give you all any number of small elements in `O(n log n)`.

If you just need the single smallest value, then you can use `min()` in linear time:

```
smallest = min(dict1.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Appreciate  for your response. is there any way we can solve this without using built in library?

Comment: You could [implement the heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) yourself? But at that point I would start to ask why. Not using _built-in_ functions is always an odd restriction.

Comment: Suppose I'm looking forward to build an algorithm, not a full functional code. As per my knowledge, it's not a good idea to use built in function in algorithms, as they are independent of the programming language. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: this  takes O(N*log(N)) time.

Comment: @LukaRahne I do explain that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is woraranound, but even if you "touch" any element no more than lets say twice as in your example, you still get complexity of O(N).

```
print ([v for (v,n) in dict1.most_common() if n == 1])
```

or better as was suggested in comments (due to complexity of .const_common being O(N*log(N)))

```
print ([v for (v,n) in dict1.items() if n == 1])
```

Comment: The `items` method could be used here as well (without instantiating a new list in memory) since you aren't passing an argument to `most_common`.

Comment: @chepner does in matter in complexity wise?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Won't this for loop have a complexity of O(n). that will make O(n^2) of the whole program. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: this takes 2*O(n) that counts as O(n). That is, time this algorithm takes,  is linear to size (number of) of input.

Comment: @LukaRahne Time complexity, no. Strictly speaking, the memory complexity is O(n) either way, because in general there could be O(n) values of 1, but here we "know" ahead of time that only O(1) memory is needed.

Comment: `most_common()` creates a heap, so this is `O(n log n)` already for the creation.

Comment: @poke Ah, I missed that `most_common` returns the items ordered by occurrence (which should have been obvious, I supposed).